# Pandas pivot table - show values under same column index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble with constructing a Pandas pivot table. 
I wish to have two values `['Balance', 'WAP']` under the same column `['Delivery']`.

Here is the DataFrame constructed from a dictionary:

```
dict_data = {
    'Contract' : ['Contract 1', 'Contract 2', 'Contract 3', 'Contract 4'],
    'Contract_Date': ['01/01/2019', '02/02/2019', '03/03/2019', '04/03/2019'],
    'Delivery' : ['2019-01', '2019-01', '2019-02', '2019-03'],
    'Price' : [90, 95, 100, 105],
    'Balance': [50, 100, 150, 200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_data)

df
```

The DataFrame:

```
    Contract    Contract_Date   Delivery    Price   Balance
0   Contract 1  01/01/2019       2019-01    90      50
1   Contract 2  02/02/2019       2019-01    95      100
2   Contract 3  03/03/2019       2019-02    100     150
3   Contract 4  04/03/2019       2019-03    105     200
```

Calculate weighted average price:

```
# Create WAP - Weighted Average Price
df['Value'] = df['Balance'] * df['Price'] 
df['WAP'] = df['Value'] / df['Balance']
df
```

Pivot table construction:

```
# Use a dictionary to apply more than 1 type of aggregate onto the data
f = {'Balance': ['sum'], 'WAP': ['mean']}

df.pivot_table(
    columns='Delivery',
    values=['Balance', 'WAP'],
    index=['Contract_Date', 'Contract'],
    aggfunc=f
).replace(np.nan, '')
```

[image: pivot]
I am trying to get the 2 values to show up under the same column, for easier comparison, like the below table (manually constructed):

```
              Delivery   2019-01          2019-02          2019-03 
Contract Date Contract   Balance     WAP  Balance   WAP    Balance     WAP 
01/01/2019    Contract 1 50          90      
02/02/2019    Contract 2 100         95     
03/03/2019    Contract 3                  150       100
04/03/2019    Contract 4                                   200         105
```

Am thinking somewhere along the lines of stack/unstack for this problem? Would greatly appreciate any help as I am still rather new to Pandas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert from dictionary one elemment lists to strings for avoid 3 level MultiIndex:

```
f = {'Balance': 'sum', 'WAP': 'mean'}
```

And then use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
f = {'Balance': 'sum', 'WAP': 'mean'}

df = (df.pivot_table(
    columns='Delivery',
    values=['Balance', 'WAP'],
    index=['Contract_Date', 'Contract'],
    aggfunc=f
     ).replace(np.nan, '')
       .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
       .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
Delivery                 2019-01     2019-02      2019-03     
                         Balance WAP Balance  WAP Balance  WAP
Contract_Date Contract                                        
01/01/2019    Contract 1      50  90                          
02/02/2019    Contract 2     100  95                          
03/03/2019    Contract 3                 150  100             
04/03/2019    Contract 4                              200  105
```

Comment: dear @jezrael thank you for helping me out. however, i wish to achieve the final df in my question (i have just edited it for more clarity) where the 2 values ```Balance``` and ```WAP``` are shown on a shared column index of ```Delivery```

Comment: amazing.. thank you so much for your help i appreciate it

Comment: dear @jezrael, I realized that my Weighted Average Price calculation is wrong. Have edited my question to add WAP function and np.average function to calculate new weighted average price, but both are wrong.. would appreciate any guidance

Comment: @yongsheng - There is problem I solve your reshape problem, not count problem.

Comment: @yongsheng - Is possible add expected output for verify?

Comment: very sorry am not sure if i should post new question for count problem.. one second and let me add expected output

Comment: @yongsheng - Not so easy, but need some time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193529/discussion-between-yongsheng-and-jezrael).